# FCM Cannot recieve notification when app in background react native ios when custom data sent

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have succesfully integrating react-native-fcm and
i am getting notification when i am sending from firebase console (in foreground,background,and killed state of app)
but when i am sending it from our server with custom data i cannot recieved when app is in (killed,background) state

i have also tried content-availble:true in data object

below is the notification data which i am sending

```
{
aps =     {
    "content-available" = 1;
};
body = "Get a free T-Shirt @WROGN on every purchase via Shopholix. T&C apply.";
"gcm.message_id" = "0:1475746605785619%9a4a567a9a4a567a";
"gcm.notification.data" = "{\"image\":\"http:\\/\\/res.cloudinary.com\\/saurabh\\/image\\/upload\\/v1469791885\\/media\\/yljgxgmfg1qbulxzwakm.png\",\"user_type\":\"all\",\"screen\":\"store\",\"id\":\"56d7e33ce69f7c8f06550002\",\"title\":\"Shopholix\",\"message\":\"Get a free T-Shirt @WROGN on every purchase via Shopholix. T&C apply.\",\"body\":\"Get a free T-Shirt @WROGN on every purchase via Shopholix. T&C apply.\"}";
"gcm.notification.priority" = high;
id = 56d7e33ce69f7c8f06550002;
image = "http://res.cloudinary.com/saurabh/image/upload/v1469791885/media/yljgxgmfg1qbulxzwakm.png";
message = "Get a free T-Shirt @WROGN on every purchase via Shopholix. T&C apply.";
screen = store;
title = Shopholix;
"user_type" = all;
```

}

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your `content_available` is set to `1`. I'm pretty sure when using FCM, you should use `true` or `false`. Correct me if I'm reading your payload structure in a wrong way, but are you specifying the `content_available` separate from the GCM payload?

Also, the `priority` parameter should be outside the `notification` payload parameter.

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve your issue?

Looking at the JSON, if it is exactly how you're sending it, then it is not well formed. All of the keys need to be strings surrounded by quotes. And each key-value pair needs to be comma-separated, not semi-colon.